# How Access Config in Griffon

Tags: griffon

I'm completely new to Griffon and have simple question I surprised I couldn't found the answer...

How I can access my per environment settings I defined in `Config.groovy` in the service.

```
environments {
    development {
        awserver.url = "http://localhost:8080/app"
    }

    production {
        awserver.url = "xxx"
    }
}
```

I tried injecting `griffonApplication` (in analogy with grails) and use griffonApplication.config, but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environmental settings are automatically merged in the application's config.
Services (as any other GriffonArtifact) have a GriffonApplication property whose name is "app", so the following should work

```
class SampleService {
    def serviceMethod() {
        URL url = app.config.awserver.url.toURL()
        // do something with url
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to access config in any other way, like ConfigurationHolder.config in grails?

Comment: Yes, simply grab hold of the application instance using griffon.util.ApplicationHolder. Griffon does not expose an additional holder for the configuration object (like Grails does), all access is through the application instance.